# Submit button doesn't work with dropdownlist in mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, button, submit

i'm new in mvc. I have a problem with my project. I use code first for my two datatables and scaffolding. All is good with my first datatable, but when i'm trying add information to second table with foreignkey ,,KlasaId" (dropdownlist) from first table, submit button doesn't work. Here is my code for first table:

```
namespace dziennik.Models
{
public class Klasa
{
    public int KlasaId { get; set; }

    public string NAZWA { get; set; }

    public int Rok_szkolny { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Uczen> Uczen { get; set; }

}
}

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Klasa] (
[KlasaId]     INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[NAZWA]       NVARCHAR (2) NOT NULL,
[Rok_szkolny] INT          NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Klasa] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([KlasaId] ASC)
);
```

Second table:

```
namespace dziennik.Models
{
public class Uczen
{
    public int UczenId { get; set; }

    public int KlasaId { get; set; }

    .
    .
    .

    public virtual Klasa Klasa { get; set; }

}
}

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Uczen] (
[UczenId]         INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[KlasaId]         INT            NOT NULL,
.
.
.
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Uczen] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UczenId] ASC),

CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Uczen_dbo.Klasa_KlasaId] FOREIGN KEY ([KlasaId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Klasa] ([KlasaId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_KlasaId]
ON [dbo].[Uczen]([KlasaId] ASC);
```

DbContext:

```
public class UczniowieContext : DbContext

{
    public UczniowieContext() :base("UczniowieConnection")
    { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Uczen>().ToTable("Uczen");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Klasa>().ToTable("Klasa");
    }

    public DbSet<Klasa> Klasy { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Uczen> Uczniowie { get; set; }

}
```

Controller:

```
// GET: DodawanieUzytkownika1/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.KlasaId = new SelectList(db.Klasy, "KlasaId", "NAZWA");
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "UczenId,KlasaId,Imie_ucz,Nazwisko_ucz,Pesel,Data_ur_ucz,Miejsce_ur,Adres_zam,Imie_opiek_rodz,Kontakt")] Uczen uczen)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Uczniowie.Add(uczen);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.KlasaId = new SelectList(db.Klasy, "KlasaId", "NAZWA", uczen.KlasaId);
    return View(uczen);
    }
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.KlasaId, "KlasaId",    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-md-10">
@Html.DropDownList("KlasaId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.KlasaId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'submit button doesn't work' ? 
Does it give any error ? 
Also please provide code of the view that has the 'submit' button.

Comment: I don't have any error. When I try update my table ,,Uczen" with new data, after submit form my page is only reload. The form is still filled but my table is empty. I don't have idea what's wrong with my code.

   `<div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>`

Comment: I don't see any code to post the values to the expected Action method - 'Create'.
Could you try changing your submit code to the below:
    `@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "DodawanieUzytkownika1", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="form-group"> 
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
         <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}`

Comment: Thank you, but I still have the same problem :/

Comment: That is weird. 
Do you have any custom routes in the RouteConfig?
Also could you please confirm that the controller name is "DodawanieUzytkownika1" ?

Comment: Yes, my controller name is "DodawanieUzytkownika1". My RouteConfig: `public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }`

Comment: That is correct as well. Could you check in fiddler if any call goes to the server on click of the submit button ?

Comment: [GET](http://i1383.photobucket.com/albums/ah281/Majki1993/Others/get_zpsjgx9q2je.png~original)
[POST](http://i1383.photobucket.com/albums/ah281/Majki1993/Others/post_zpsmqwznrmp.png~original)

Comment: POST response says 200 from server. So definitely hitting the method in the server. 
Try putting a break point in Create Post Action ?

Comment: I found my problem. Create post action wanted ID which I didn't have in my form (because id is auto incremate). Thank you very much for your help @Boney Greetings from Poland :)

Comment: Wondering how ID didnt show up in the form.
Sure. Happy to help, even though not able to solve the problem.
Cheers Mike. :)